# Error : Header may not contain more than a single header, new line

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hello :) Below i will told i'm not the best at english i know i will learn english to not scoff your language i'm so sorry.

1. I have a problem with my function (yeah i know that so long).
   My problem is one : i'm getting this error with the function: `checkout()`,

Error : Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected.

//I have fix this error ago because i have code 3 `try{}` and `catch(){}` for the gesture of error.

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $name = $inputs['name'];
    $address = $inputs['address'];
    $city = $inputs['city'];
    $state = $inputs['state'];
    $zip = $inputs['zip'];
    $item = Session::get('cart');
    $helper = Session::get('cart')->items;
    foreach ($helper as $table_row){
        $order = new Order();

        $id = $table_row['item']['id'];
        $token = $item->items[$id]['item']['token'];
        $seller = User::all()->where('token','=',$token)->first();

        $product_name = $item->items[$id]['item']['title'];
        $product_quantity = $item->items[$id]['qty'];
        $product_price = $item->items[$id]['price'];
        $product_total = $product_price * $product_quantity;

        $order->order_token = Str::random(random_int(10,20));
        $order->buyer_token = auth()->user()->token;
        $order->seller_token = $seller->token;
        $order->pending_payment = 0;
        $order->shipping_price = 0;
        $order->total_price = $item->totalPrice;
        $order->delivered = 0;
        $order->billing_info = $gpg_msg;
        $order->save();
    }
    return redirect(view('client.dashboard'));
```

2. i'm make an site with seller admin and client account (that important), so i'm making the cart and i'm storing them on the `Session::class` with the name `'cart'`, the cart work very well.

But now on the code below i want to iterate the cart to take the token, ( the token is `unique()` for all user, if a seller create a product the token is insert into the row of products table.).

Google Traduction ( sorry )
after iterating on the basket I would like to retrieve the vendor's tokens (as there may be several products from different vendors in a basket) to send them their order to each of these vendors.

I am missing only the solution for this problem which I tear my hair since this morning.

Thank you for someone helping.

Answer (score 1):

In the last line you asking to make a redirect with return redirect(). This only take a string with the url you want to redirect to.

As the url parameter to redirect you are returning a whole HTML page.

I you want to redirect them to the dashboard you should do something like this (with the correct url of course) `return redirect('/dashboard');`

If you just want to display the page then remove the redirect like `return view('client.dashboard');`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you laus brand :)

Comment: You're welcome. If it solves your problem please mark the answer as a correct answer :)